# Is it possible to determine if a function is called in the body of another function or as argument of a function?

Tags: python, code-analysis

Suppose we have a Python function:

```
def func():
    # if called in the body of another function, do something
    # if called as argument to a function, do something different
    pass
```

func() can be called in the body of another function:

```
def funcA():
    func()
```

func() can be also called as an argument to a function:

```
def funcB(arg1):
    pass

def funcC(**kwargs):
    pass

funcB(func())
funcC(kwarg1=func())
```

Is there a way to distinguish between those two case in the body of func()?

EDIT. Here is my use case. I'd like to use Python as a language for rule based 3D model generation. Each rule is a small Python function. Each subsequent rule refines the model and adds additional details. [Here](https://github.com/vvoovv/prokitektura-examples/blob/master/examples/simple01.py) is an example rule set. [Here](https://github.com/vvoovv/prokitektura-blender/wiki/Tutorial) is a tutorial describing how the rule set works. My rule language mimics a rule language called CGA shape grammar. If this StackExchange question can be solved, my rule language could be significantly simplified.

EDIT2. Code patching would also suffice for me. For example all cases when func is called in the body of another function are substituted for something like

```
call_function_on_the_right()>>func()
```

Comment: Why would you need to know this? What is your usecase?

Comment: Sounds like you actually have two different functions that you've crammed into one.

Comment: And the second form is just an expression, whose *output* is used as an argument for `funcB()`. You could also have `foo = func()` then `funcB(foo)` and there would be no difference. Or `foo = func` (note, no *call*, just a reference to the same function), then `funcB(foo())`, calling the same function object.

Comment: It'll be far easier to just have the caller pass in an argument to vary behaviour, or have them use *different* functions.

Comment: There is no simple way - `func` should not have to know or care where the values it `return`s are going to do its job.

Comment: I agree with @JoshCaswell but I will say it stronger - bad design. you can do a lot of things with python introspection, but I don't think this should be one of them.

Comment: But to stay strictly on-topic: I'd imagine that in Python it is possible - in this simple form, you could go up the stack trace, and parse the source code of the parent scope. However, in general very hard, just consider: `funcB(objectThatWillCallArg(lambda: func())())`, and further complications.

Comment: I added use case description.

Comment: This analysis can be really ugly.  Consider eval('...func(...)...').  Ignoring that case, what does it mean for func to be called in an argument of bar, but not in the body of another function?  What if the call to bar is embedded in a function?  I don't think OP's classification scheme is clear.

Comment: @IraBaxter It's important that func is called in an argument of bar. It doesn't matter for my use case if bar is embedded in a function.

Comment: added EDIT2 about code patching

Comment: @woow: Then what about Pieter's objection, that "in an argument" is equilent to "assigned to temp which is used as argument"?

Comment: @IraBaxter In my use case, the combination foo = func() and funcB(foo) must not be used, since foo = func() is considered as call of func in in the body of a function

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that this might not be a good idea. You could achieve the same by requiring using eg. `funct()` on toplevel and `funca()` when as argument, and both could call the same `func()` with a keyword argument specifying whether you are on toplevel or in an argument, for example. But I'm not here to argue whether this is a good idea or not, I'm here to answer the question.

Is it possible? It might be.

How would you do this, then? Well, the first thing to know is that you can use `inspect.stack()` to get information about the context you were called from.

You could figure out the line you were called from and read the source file to see how the function is called on that line.
There are two problems with this, however.

1. The source file could've been modified and give wrong information.
2. What if you do `func(func())`? It's called in both ways on the same line!

To get accurate information, you should look at the frame objects in the stack. They have a `f_code` member that contains the bytecode and a `f_lasti` member that contains the position of the last instruction. Using those you should be able to figure out which function on the line is currently being called and where the return value is going. You have to parse the whole bytecode (have a look at the `dis` module) for the frame, though, and keep track of the internal stack used by the interpreter to see where the return value goes.

Now, I'm not 100% sure that it'll work, but I can't see why it wouldn't. The only thing I can see that could "go wrong" is if keeping track of the return value proves to be too hard. But since you only have to keep track of it for the duration of one line of code, there really shouldn't be any structures that would be "impossible" to handle, as far as I can see.

I didn't say it would be easy, only that it might be possible. :)

Comment: "The source file could've been modified and give wrong information." Could you please explain or provide an example for that case.

Comment: Thanks to your message, I've got an idea. I could count a number of round brackets before func(). If the number is even, then func() is called in the body of a function. If the number is odd. then func() is called as argument of a function. Do you think it would work?

Comment: @vvoovv Well, for example, if someone uses your "library" and has his own "parts library" for it and two separate programs that use it, and he starts the first program, then adds a new "part" that the second program needs. Now the first running program is looking at the wrong source code. Ie. any time you modify the source code while any program using it is running, it'll be completely broken. (Also if someone eg. only distributes .pyc files) Also, you can break logical lines on many physical lines, which would break your parenthesis counting solution. (And even your example file does that)